# Find coordinates of current location and figure out the country

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Is it possible to find out the coordinates of my current location and figure out which country this is in?

Comment: There are many questions and answers on this already.

Comment: What have you tried? People will be more willing to help you if you can show that you have attempted to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: These are two separate questions.  The first is to figure out your coordinates.  The second is to use geocoding to figure out where you are.

Answer (score 0):

> The [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323) class provides services for converting a map coordinate (specified as a latitude/longitude pair) into information about that coordinate, such as the country, city, or street.

```
MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate];
reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
[reverseGeocoder start];
```

Then you need to implement [MKReverseGeocoderDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate) protocol. This is the delegate method that gets called once it gets your info:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
    // get the country string from placemark.country and use however you want.
}
```